# How to avoid 429 error requests.get() in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-429, pubg

I'm trying to get some data from pubg API using `requests.get()`.

While code was executing, `response.status_code` returned `429`.

After I got `429`, I couldn't get `200`.

how to fix this situation?

Here is part of my code.

```
for num in range(len(platform)):
   url = "https://api.pubg.com/shards/"+platform[num]+"/players/"+playerID[num]+"/seasons/"+seasonID+"/ranked"
   req = requests.get(url, headers=header)
   print(req.status_code)
```

```
[output]
200
429
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   429 error means "Too many requests".  Meaning you need to ensure the api allows that many requests as well as the rate of requests.

Comment: Yeah.  Sounds like you're running into rate limiting of the site you're accessing.  Often, there's something you have to do have the site let you make more frequent requests.  Sometimes this is paying $, but other times it is just about registering and using a set of credentials to send authenticated requests.  In any case, I expect that the site itself will have documentation explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

you are sending too many requests at once/in short span of time. I recommend using `time.sleep(10)`

```
import time


for num in range(len(platform)):
   ....
   ....
   time.sleep(10)
```

To check the amount of time required between requests, check the **Header** under **Network** in Dev Tools - You should see a ***retry-after: XXX*** header.

If you get **http status code 429**, check the header under Network - You should see a *retry-after: XXX* header, which basically tells you for how long you should sleep between requests.

Comment: If you get **http status code 429**, check the header under Network - You should see a `retry-after: XXX` header, which basically tells you for how long you should sleep between requests.

Comment: Hi @DanielMizr, that sounds like a wonderful solution. Can you edit the above message to add this information?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by sam, HTTP error 429 means you are making too many requests in a certain amount of time.

According to [the official PUBG API documentation](https://documentation.pubg.com/en/rate-limits.html), the API actually tells you these rate limits by sending an additional header called `X-RateLimit-Limit` with every request. Each request also has a header called `X-RateLimit-Remaining` which tells you how many requests you have currently left until the next rate reset which happens at the time specified in the third header `X-RateLimit-Reset`.

Since you seem to use the requests library, you can access these headers with a simple `req.headers` after making your request in python.